# How do I send Enter key with PostMessage in C#?

Tags: c#, testing, postmessage

I'm trying to send some input to a window with `PostMessage`. I'm not using `SendInput` because it won't be in focus. I've got characters (`A`) being entered but how do I send the `Enter` key? This is the cut down version of my code. Its runs but `Enter` is not sent?

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

const int WM_KEYDOWN    = 0x100;
const int WM_KEYUP      = 0x101;

const Int32 WM_CHAR = 0x0102;
const Int32 VK_RETURN = 0x0D;
const int VK_ENTER = 0x0D;

IntPtr val = new IntPtr((Int32)'A');
PostMessage(WindowHandle, WM_KEYDOWN, (IntPtr)(val - 0x020), new IntPtr(0));
PostMessage(WindowHandle, WM_CHAR, (IntPtr)val, new IntPtr(0));
PostMessage(WindowHandle, WM_KEYUP, (IntPtr)(val - 0x020), new IntPtr(0));
PostMessage(WindowHandle, WM_KEYDOWN, (IntPtr)(val - 0x020), new IntPtr(0));
PostMessage(WindowHandle, VK_RETURN, (IntPtr)val, new IntPtr(0));
PostMessage(WindowHandle, WM_KEYUP, (IntPtr)(val - 0x020), new IntPtr(0));
```

Comment: There is not much point in faking the keyup/down messsages, only send the message they generated.  Just the two WM_CHAR messages.  VK_RETURN is not a message.  Always favor System.Windows.Automation instead.

Comment: I believe you have to have window focus for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're sending the enter wrong. Try this.

```
IntPtr val = new IntPtr((Int32)'A');
PostMessage(WindowHandle, WM_KEYDOWN, (IntPtr)(val - 0x020), new IntPtr(0));
PostMessage(WindowHandle, WM_CHAR, (IntPtr)val, new IntPtr(0));
PostMessage(WindowHandle, WM_KEYUP, (IntPtr)(val - 0x020), new IntPtr(0));
PostMessage(WindowHandle, WM_KEYDOWN, new IntPtr(VK_RETURN), new IntPtr(0));
PostMessage(WindowHandle, WM_KEYUP, new IntPtr(VK_RETURN), new IntPtr(0));
```

Comment: I get an "can not convert from int to System.intPrt" error when I do that sorry

Comment: Give that a shot now, sorry about that!

Comment: @jamie Did that help?